# Confused about scalar multiplication within a set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be the union of the first and third quadrants of the $xy$ plane. $$W={x \choose y}:xy\geq0$$

Now if $u$ is in $W$ and $c$ is any scalar, is $cu$ in $W$? Obviously the answer is yes. Since $W$ consists of the vectors $u$ with either positive x and y coordinates, or negative x and y coordinates. Multiplying $u$ with any positive or negative scalar, will either give us the additive inverse $-(u)$ multiplied by $c$ or simply multiply the length of $u$, both contained in $W$. I'm trying to prove this more rigorously, but my book justifies it with the following operation $$cu=c{x \choose y}={cx \choose cy}=(cx)(cy)=c^2(xy)$$

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I just don't follow this logic at all. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I suspect that the "equals" in ${cx \choose cy}=(cx)(cy)$ was put there by mistake, and they meant to say that the vector $cu$ also satisfies the requirement for $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what your book says, then your book is just plain wrong since, in fact,$$\begin{bmatrix}cx\\cy\end{bmatrix}\neq(cx)(cy),$$since $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}cx\\cy\end{smallmatrix}\right]\in\mathbb R^2$, whereas $(cx)(cy)\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

After multiplying by the scalar they’re checking whether the product of the new coordinates agrees with the conditions for $W$. Since $c^2\geq 0$,$xy\geq 0$, we have that $c^2(xy)\geq 0$ so therefore belongs to $W$.